# HttpSession is null

Tags: jsf, servlets

```
A)         FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
           ExternalContext externalContext=facesContext.getExternalContext();
           HttpSession session = (HttpSession) externalContext.getSession(false);

               if(session.isNew()) {            //  java.lang.NullPointerException

B)         HttpServletRequest req1 = (HttpServletRequest)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
                                    .getExternalContext().getRequest();
           HttpSession session1=req1.getSession();

             if(session1.isNew()) {            // no Exception
```

why case A is throwing NullPointerException where as case B is not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, it's important to understand *when* and *why* a `NullPointerException` is been thrown. The way you put the question indicates that you don't understand it. You asked "Why does it throw `NullPointerException`?". You didn't ask "Why does it return `null`?".

As its [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html) indicates, the `NullPointerException` will be thrown when you try to access a variable or to invoke a method using the period `.` operator on an object reference which is *actually* `null`.

E.g.

```
SomeObject someObject = null;
someObject.doSomething(); // NullPointerException!
```

In your particular case, you were trying to invoke the method `isNew()` on a `null` object. This is thus not possible. The `null` reference has no methods at all. It simply points to *nothing*. You should be doing a null-check instead.

```
HttpSession session = (HttpSession) externalContext.getSession(false);

if (session == null) {
    // There's no session been created during current nor previous requests.
}
else if (session.isNew()) {
    // The session has been created during the current request.
}
else {
    // The session has been created during one of the previous requests.
}
```

The `getSession()` call with `false` argument may namely return `null` when the session hasn't been created yet. See also the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#getSession%28boolean%29):

> #### getSession
>
> ```
> public abstract java.lang.Object getSession(boolean create)
> ```
>
> If the `create` parameter is `true`, create (if necessary) and return a session instance associated with the current request. If the `create` parameter is `false` return any existing session instance associated with the current request, **or return `null` if there is no such session.**

See the emphasized part.

The `HttpServletRequest#getSession()` call which doesn't take any argument, uses by default `true` as `create` argument. See also the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getSession%28%29):

> #### getSession
>
> ```
> HttpSession getSession()
> ```
>
> Returns the current session associated with this request, **or if the request does not have a session, creates one**.

See the emphasized part.

I hope that you'll take this as a hint to consult the javadocs better. They contain more than often already the answers to your questions as they describe very precisely what the classes and methods do.

Answer (score 1):

The default for getSession() is to create a new Session if there is no current session.

Using getSession(false) changes this behaviour to return null if there is no active session.